# How can you parse a Java 64-bit long from a binary file into a PHP string?

Tags: php, 64-bit, binary, long-integer

I've used unpack to convert most of the data types I have in a binary file that I'm parsing with little problems. I have no idea how to work with a big endian 64-bit signed long. I think this data type is stored using 2's complement. The application of the data file I'm reading is a java app so I assume it's 2's complement. I don't need to work with it as a number but simply work with it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Java 64-bit integers are indeed stored natively as "network-order" (big endian, i.e. start with the most significant byte) 8-byte 2's complement format. So typically you take byte at a time, shift left by 8, repeat. Byte values can be thought of as unsigned (while result is signed), but with left-shifting this should not matter.
So: first you just created equivalent 64-bit int from bytes, and display from there. No point in using short cuts; while it is possible, you just end up with more complicated and less efficient code.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that the PHP I'm working with is 32-bit. I guess I need to try working with the BCMath library or some such?

Comment: I don't think 32-bitness matters in this case, it should not affect existence of 'bigger' datatypes (rather matters with addressing etc). But I am bit of PHP newbie so I hope others can confirm this.

Comment: PHP's integer size is dependent on the platform. A 32-bit OS will only have a 32-bit signed integer. Anything that overflows will be cast to a float.

Answer (score 0):

32-bit PHP will only have signed 32-bit integers, thus as far as I know, there's no way to natively unpack the data.

The following code should be able to read a big endian, two's complement 64-bit integer:

```
<?php
function read_int64($fp)
{
  $hex = unpack('H16a', fread($fp, 8));
  $hex = '0x'.$hex['a'];

  $n = gmp_init($hex);

  if (gmp_testbit($n, 63))
  {
    $n = gmp_xor($n, '0xffffffffffffffff'); // flip the bits
    $n = gmp_neg(gmp_add($n, 1));           // add one and negate
  }

  return gmp_strval($n);
}
?>
```

It returns the integer as a string. It can be used like:

```
$fp = fopen('test.bin', 'rb');
echo read_int64($fp)."\n";
fclose($fp);
```

(Edit: Updated code to call fewer GMP functions.)